# How can I convert values from one column into a quoted, comma-separated list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I am using SQLServer2008.

In my table there is one field 'Code'.

When i write query

```
select Code from Table1
```

then it gives below output

```
Code
----
 9
 8 
 7
 6
 5
 10
 31
```

and my required output is :

```
["9","8","7","6","5","10","31"]
```

I have approx 14000 code in Table.
How can i get this result? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(Code INT)
INSERT INTO @temp (Code)
VALUES (9),(8),(7),(6),(5),(10),(31)

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ', "' + CAST(Code AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"'
    FROM @temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '[') + ']'
```

Output:

```
["9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "10", "31"]
```

Comment: Thanks its work but i edited my question. I have approx 14000 code in my table.

Comment: replace 
`INSERT INTO @temp (Code) VALUES (9),(8),(7),(6),(5),(10),(31)`
with
`INSERT INTO @temp (Code) select Code from Table1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query:

```
DECLARE @var varchar(8000)
SET @var = '['
SELECT @var = @var + '"' + convert(varchar(100),Code) + '",' FROM Table1
SET @var = SUBSTRING(@var,0,LEN(@var)) + ']'

SELECT @var
```

`SUBSTRING(@var,0,LEN(@var))` removes unnecessary comma at the end of the string

Comment: Very risky, and not guaranteed to work. If the server generates a parallel plan, it may evaluate `@var = @var + '"' + convert(varchar(100),Code) + '",'` on multiple threads and not serialize access to the variable, resulting in some rows being ommitted from the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @Str = COALESCE(@Str + ',', '') + '"'+CAST(Code AS VARCHAR(50))+'"'
FROM    Table1


SELECT  '['+@Str+']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
declare @formattdstring varchar(100)
set @formattdstring=''
select @formattdstring=@formattdstring+'"'+ Code +'",' from Table1
select '['+@formattdstring+']' as formattedstring
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Very risky, and not guaranteed to work. If the server generates a parallel plan, it may evaluate `@formattdstring=@formattdstring+'"'+ Code +'",'` on multiple threads and not serialize access to the variable, resulting in some rows being ommitted from the result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever any proofs?

Comment: Fully agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment. Sorry, but your query is a bad practice.